# Multiple Linkify patterns - App not responding Android

Tags: android, pattern-matching, linkify

I am trying to linkify my textview. The text is loaded from the database and linkify is called.

```
    Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    Pattern phone = Pattern.compile("\\+?\\d[\\d -]{8,12}\\d");
    Linkify.addLinks(text,phone, "tel:");
    Pattern email = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+\\.*[a-z]*");
    Linkify.addLinks(text,email, "mailto:");
```

I have tried like this.

Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

But this actually have the scheme "http" or "https". So when I click a link like http://something.com/file.pdf , the url is not correcly matched and the pdf is not displayed.

So I tried pattern for web also.

```
    Pattern phone = Pattern.compile("\\+?\\d[\\d -]{8,12}\\d");
    Linkify.addLinks(text,phone, "tel:");
    Pattern email = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+\\.*[a-z]*");
    Linkify.addLinks(text,email, "mailto:");
    Pattern web = Pattern.compile("^(https?:\\/\\/)?([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,6})([\\/\\w \\.-]*)*\\/?$");
    Linkify.addLinks(text, web,"");
```

But when I tried this code, the activity is not loaded and the app terminates as not responding. Logcat doesn't show anything about what happens. So I don't know why the error occur. Do anyone has the idea why this happen and how to solve this?

The log is here:

```
03-30 07:28:51.839 28870-28875/com.example.application I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=103KB, data=58KB
03-30 07:28:51.841 28870-28875/com.example.application I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=99KB, data=50KB
03-30 07:28:52.074 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:28:53.163 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:28:54.646 28870-28875/com.example.application I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=118KB, data=79KB
03-30 07:28:54.647 28870-28875/com.example.application I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=118KB, data=79KB
Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
03-30 07:28:54.651 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:28:54.739 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:28:54.755 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:28:55.523 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:28:56.039 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:28:57.658 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:28:57.938 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:28:59.678 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:28:59.951 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:29:00.717 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:29:01.017 28870-28875/com.example.application I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=247KB, data=175KB
03-30 07:29:01.019 28870-28875/com.example.application I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=244KB, data=139KB
03-30 07:29:01.441 28870-28881/com.example.application I/zygote: NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 2967(269KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 1867KB/3MB, paused 934us total 273.344ms
03-30 07:29:01.724 28870-28881/com.example.application I/zygote: NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 4946(323KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 1592KB/3MB, paused 1.114ms total 154.884ms
03-30 07:29:01.883 28870-28870/com.example.application I/Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-30 07:29:01.910 28870-28875/com.example.application I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=245KB, data=148KB
03-30 07:29:01.911 28870-28875/com.example.application I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=245KB, data=148KB
Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
03-30 07:29:01.928 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:29:02.125 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:29:02.145 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:29:03.070 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:29:03.994 28870-28875/com.example.application I/zygote: JIT allocated 56KB for compiled code of void android.view.View.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
03-30 07:29:04.124 28870-28890/com.example.application D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x990fc120: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa517c0a0)
03-30 07:29:06.973 28870-28881/com.example.application I/zygote: NativeAllocBackground concurrent copying GC freed 1952(196KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 1785KB/3MB, paused 647us total 112.103ms
```

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: how do I get it?

Comment: Use `adb` to take logs. For example: `adb logcat -v time`.

Comment: on Terminal , it says 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I checked the logcat but nothing is displayed.

Comment: You can also look at the logcat logs using Android Studio too: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html#running

Comment: added the log. .

Comment: Post a log that contains the error or exception. Reproduce your issue and in the log there will probably be something called an `Exception`. That tells you what went wrong.

Comment: it has nothing as exception I tried many times and that is why I had to post here.